# Firebase - How to disable user using Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to work out an *enable/disable* user cloud function. When using the admin SDK to disable the user, I get the response: *that the disabled property is read only*. Can someone help me out? The data that is passed to the function, is the user ID.

```
 export const disableUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log(data);

    admin.auth().updateUser(data, {
        disabled: true
    }).then(() => {
        admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data).update({ disabled: true})
            .then(() =>  {
                console.log(`Successfully disabled user: ${data}`);

                return 200;
            })
            .catch((error => console.log(error)));        
    }).catch( error => console.log(error));

    return 500;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the value of `data` is the `uid`? What do you get if you do `console.log(data);`. You may use a property of `data` in order to get the `uid` value. Your code needs to be adapted to correctly return a promise and handle the error (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) but if you do `return admin.auth().updateUser(...)` it should work, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user.

Answer (score 3):

I used typeScript for Cloud Functions.

index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const disableUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const userId = data.userId;
  return functions.app.admin.auth().updateUser(userId, {disabled: true});
});
```

In my app, I called "disableUser" function like this:

```
import {AngularFireFunctions} from '@angular/fire/functions';

export class AppComponent {

data$: Observable<any>;
callable: (data: any) => Observable<any>;

constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {
  this.callable = fns.httpsCallable('disableUser');
  this.data$ = this.callable({userId: 'ZDxaTS0SoYNYqUVJuLLiXSLkd8A2'});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to return an HTTP status code from your function.  It doesn't work that way.  Please [read the documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to understand what to return.

Since you are performing asynchronous work in your function (`updateUser()`, then `update()`), you need to return a promise that resolves with the data to send to the client.  Right now, you are just returning `500` before the async work completes.  At the very least, you need to return the promise from `update()` so that Cloud Functions knows when your async work is done.

```
return admin.auth().updateUser(...)
.then(() => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data).update(...)
})
```

It's crucial to understand how promises work when deal with Cloud Functions for Firebase.  You can't just return whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for the tip. I am indeed still working out how to properly implement these cloud functions. However, all the code seems to run fine.  Could you please let me know if this approach of disabling is correct? The function logs that the disabled property is read only.

Comment: I tried it out, and turns out it works fine by adding the returns. Thanks a lot!